# Why jQuery .length isn't updated?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to make a character counter with a "success" message.

My **problem** is that after the user has reached the desired number of characters and the "success" message is displayed, **if he erases characters the "success" message stays**.

I would think it would calculate every "keyup" but I guess I'm missing something. Would appreciate any ideas.

Here is the code:

```js
$('#count').text(10);
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length < 10) {
        $('#count').text(10 - $(this).val().length);
    } else {
      $('.enoughText').text('ok now.');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<p class="enoughText">you have more <span id="count"></span> to go.</p>
```

Comment: Because once you hit the 10 characters the `<span id="count"></span>` is removed because you overwrite it with `$('.enoughText').text('ok now.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5jq9cge1/1/)

The issue was when you were writing the success text, you were overwriting the area of the code that you stored your counter.

To resolve this, you can just work with everything in the same container:

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<p class="response">you have more 10 to go.</p>
```

**JS**

```
if($(this).val().length < 10) {
    $('.response').text("you have more " + parseInt(10 - $(this).val().length, 10) + " to go.");
}
else{
    $('.response').text('ok now.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Stupid me :)

Comment: @Ben Glad I could help!

Comment: Just a little comment about the suggested solution - it is acting a little bit weird (not updating the text after hitting 9 charchters but after 7 letters left then sayng youve got 1 left instead of 3 left...)

Comment: @Ben Oops I think it acted a little weird because I changed the event from `keyup` to `keydown`. I changed it back and it seems to be working fine!

Comment: Great! Thanks! (my plan was to finish the comment here but funny enough the sentence beneath this comment text field says "1 more to go..." :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you update the whole paragraph with the class `.enoughText`. If 10 is reached the span with the ID count will be removed.

My suggestion:

```
if ($(this).val().length < 10) {
  $('.enoughText').text('you have more ' + (10 - $(this).val().length) + ' to go.');
} else {
  $('.enoughText').text('ok now.');
}
```